# How do I upload a video to my Facebook page using the graph API?

Tags: typescript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've been struggling with how to interpret the documentation obtained [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/video-uploads) and [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/videos). I'm using [Facebook's Javascript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/).

```
    async postVideo(page: IFacebookPage, videoFile: File): Promise<CreateAdResult> {
        return new Promise<CreateAdResult>(async (resolve, reject) => {
            try {
                const data = new FormData()
                data.append('source', videoFile)
                const result = await this.post(`/${page.id}/videos`, page, { source: data })
                resolve(result)
            } catch (error) { reject(error) }
        })
    }

    private async post(url: string, page: IFacebookPage, params: any): Promise<CreateAdResult> {
        return new Promise<CreateAdResult>(async (resolve, reject) => {
            const accessToken = await this.fetchFaceBookPageAccessToken(page.id)
            this.FB().api(url, "post", { ...params, access_token: accessToken }, (response: any) => {
                if (response && !response.error) {
                    resolve(CreateAdResult.PublishToFacebookSuccess)
                } else {
                    const msg = response && response.error ? `Failed to post content to Facebook page with error: ${response.error.message} ` : `Failed to post ad to Facebook page!`
                    reject(Error(msg)) // <----- Ends up here!!
                }
            })
        })
    }
```

All this just results in an error message on the form

> Error: Failed to post content to Facebook page with error: There was a
>   problem uploading your video file. Please try again.

Comment: That error message seems to come from your `post` method, and not actually the `postVideo` one – suggesting it might not actually the video uploading part that fails?

Comment: @04FS It's just caught there first. The reason is probably incorrect format of the data to be uploaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around the problem by uploading the video somewhere else and provide the url to Facebook instead.

I.e.

```
async postVideo(page: IFacebookPage, videoUrl: string): Promise<CreateAdResult> {
    return new Promise<CreateAdResult>(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const result = await this.post(`/${page.id}/videos`, page, { file_url: videoUrl })
            resolve(result)
        } catch (error) { reject(error) }
    })
}
```